# Updating user authentication map in Clojure Friend

Tags: clojure

In Friend authentication library for Clojure, one can use `friend/authenticate` with a map parameter in order to configure the library. In my case the call to `friend/authenticate` looks like this:

```
  (friend/authenticate {:login-uri "/login"
                        :default-landing-uri "/index.html"
                        :unauthorized-redirect-uri "/login"
                        :credential-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn @users/*users*)
                        :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})
```

Notice that `:credential-fn` gets passed a reference to a global atom `*users*`. In my application, users can be dynamically added/removed/updated, and `*users*` contains a dynamically updated map of user entries.

How can i configure Friend so that it would know about changes to `*users*`? If i pass deref-ed version, then it seems that Friend would only know about users available at application initialization time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the partial function derefs the value of the user map when the partial function is created. So changes to the map won't change the behavior of the partial function you defined.

You can define your own credentials function like this :

```
(friend/authenticate routes
  {:credential-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn
                    (fn [username]
                      (load-creds username))) ;the code can be simplified here
   :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})
```

Where load-creds is a function that loads a credentials for specific username. This function should return something like :

```
{:username "some-username"
 :password (creds/hash-bcrypt "user_password")
 :roles #{::user}}
```

This way you can do whatever you want (e.g. load accounts information from database rather than a map). But you can also use the map still if you want. In case you want to keep using map, you can define load-creds as :

```
(defn load-creds [username]
   (get @users/*users* username))
```

Comment: Thanks! It wonderfully works! I am having problems when determining if a specific value is bound at compile-time or run-time, your answer shed some light on it.